# Can't change footer colour in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I have spent hours trying to figure out what's going wrong, but I can't seem to figure out why I can't change the colour of the text in my wordpress footer.

Here's the code for footer.php:

```
<div id="footer">

<div class="fcred">
Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <a href="<?php
bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php
bloginfo('name'); ?></a> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?><br />
<?php fflink();?> | <a href="info@XXX.com" title="Contact Developer">Developed by XXX</a> Design by <a href="http://www.XXX.com" title="WordPress Themes">XXX Themes</a>.
</div>  
<div class='clear'></div>   

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

below are the relevant CSS lines - I've tried to change everything to white, but nothing changes in the actual site:

```
#footer {
    padding:5px 0 5px 0px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:11px;
    background:#000 ;
    z-index: 200;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px !important;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    }

#footer a:link , #footer a:visited{
    color:#FFF;
    }

#footer a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    }


.fcred {
    width:700px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;
    line-height:16px;   
}
```

Nothing I do seems to make any change on the actual site. I'm fairly sure the code is OK and it seems like it's being overridden somehow, but I have no idea where to look. I'm fairly new to Wordpress in general so would appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using a caching plugin?

Comment: Hi diggy, I deactivated all plugins to try narrow it down. Solved the issue (quick fix) by changing the color style in-line in the footer.php file: <div id="footer" style="color:#FFF">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to inspect the page elements once their processed by the browser?

In chrome, right-click the element in question and select, "Inspect Element."

If FireFox, look in to downloading FireBug add-on as it's better than the default FF inspection tool.

Both of these add-ons will tell you exactly, whether inline or from a stylesheet, where the styling is coming from.

Comment: Hey. I took a look using the Inspect Element tool and it seems <div id="footer"> and <div class="fcred"> are the main culprits. There is a third one labelled <div id="su-footer-links"> which isn't in my CSS and  seems to be a remnant of the theme I started out with - there are some  references to some javascript after this div. I have no experience with js so not sure if these could be the culprit?

Comment: Absolutely. Javascript can alter an HTML element by placing CSS inline to that elementor  add/remove classes to elements, increasing the complexity of your styling.  In Chrome, the Inspect Element tool will show you inactive attributes by putting a line through inactive attributes.  There's also a checkbox that lets you turn that attribute on and off.  A browser will always go with the most recent attribute definition; the most recently loaded style sheet, the most recently defined style, and finally any inline style.

Comment: Thanks a million tPlummer - I think the JS has messed some things around. The style sheet is relatively complicated and I can't figure out exactly where the problem is. If I change any of the styling under #footer, nothing happens, but what I have done is changed the style in-line in the footer.php file which seems to have done the trick. Not the most elegant solution, but it will do for my immediate needs. Thanks for the time!

Comment: A style sheeting can have multiple attribute definition for the same element, which might be causing your problem.  Don't forget to accept answer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of troubleshooting ideas for you:

- Try using !important after the background style on #footer to see if it overrides
- Assign the background style to .fcred instead
- Remove clearboth from #footer

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried each of the above suggestions and nothing seemed to change. The main text remains a slightly off-black, and the links are blue. Any other ideas?